# Random matrix invertible

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices, matrix-inverse

I am trying to figure out why the following random matrix is invertible:

\begin{align*}
A_j = I_d + J_{\mu}(\hat{X}_{t_{j-1}})(t_j - t_{j-1}) + 
\left( \begin{array}{rrr}
B_1^T \\                                              
\vdots  \\
B_d^T \\                                              
\end{array}\right) \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}
\end{align*}
with
\begin{align*}
B_l = \Delta W_{t_{j}}^T J_{\sigma_l}(\hat{X}_{t_{j-1}}) \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times d}, 
\end{align*}
whereas
\begin{split} 
\hat{ X}_{t_{j+1}}&:= \hat{X}_{t_j} + \mu (\hat{X}_{t_j}) \Delta t_i + \sigma (\hat{X}_{t_j}) \Delta W_{t_{j+1}},
\end{split}
and
\begin{align*}
\hat{ X}_{t_{0}} = x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^d
\end{align*}
the Euler discretization of a SDE X is. For
\begin{align*}
\mu : \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\sigma : \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{d \times m}
\end{align*}
we assume that they are globally lipschitz continuous and in continuously differentiable and with
\begin{align*}
\Delta W_{t_i} := (W_{t_i} - W_{t_{i-1}})
\end{align*}
I mean the increment of a Brownian motion with dimension $m$. With $J_{\sigma_l}$ I denote the Jacobian matrix.

I know that under the lebesgue measure the measure is zero that $A_j$ is not invertible. Now I want to show that the matrix $A_j$ is invertible under the probability measure with probability 1. My idea would be to show that the terms in the matrix are absolutely continuous with respect to the lebesgue measure. For a gaussian distributed random variable I understand that this is true. My problem is that I do not see how I can proof that the Jacobian of $ \mu$ and $ \sigma$ and the Euler discretisation are absolutely continuous.

I would appreciate any references or hint!